# Sum of lowest numbers that are part of an arithmetic sequence

Tags: python, sequence

I would like to iterate through a list of integers, calculate the sum of the lowest numbers that belongs to an arithmetic sequence with common difference 1 + the numbers that are not part of a sequence:

```
mylist = [2,3,4,10,12,13]
```

So, from mylist it would be 2 (from 2,3,4) + 10 (not part of a sequence) + 12 (from 12,13)

I've managed to make something work, but I could only figure out how to do it, if the list is reversed. And I am sure there is a better/cleaner solution that mine:

```
mylist = [13,12,10,4,3,2]

result = mylist[-1] #if I don't do this, I don't know how to grab the last item in the list
for i in range(len(mylist)-1):
    if mylist[i] - mylist[i+1] == 1:
        continue
    else:
        result += mylist[i]
```

Hope someone will help me out, and that I get a little wiser in my coding journey. Thanks.

Comment: could you pleas give sample input and output?

Comment: Sample IP = `mylist = [2,3,4,10,12,13]`; Sample OP = 2 (from 2,3,4) + 10 (not part of a sequence) + 12 (from 12,13) = `24`

Comment: You don't need to reverse the list mylist[i+1]-mylist[i]==1 and result would be mylist[0]

Comment: @Aditya Gupta, If I understand you correctly, your suggestion is the first thing I tried. But then I can only get it to catch 2,4,10.

Comment: @Jarvis Just because there are nested loops doesn't mean it's O(N^2) :) Every iteration inside the inner nested loop in my solution takes away an iteration on the outer nested loop, which means the whole thing still has a max of N iterations, making it O(N) due to the loop bodies all being O(1).

Comment: I didn’t checkout the loop that closely, but it’s still at-least O(N * log (N)) due to the sorting of the input list (assuming timsort's worst/average case sorting time complexity).

Comment: Accepted answer is not efficient (worst-case O(N * log(N))) and my answer was downvoted without any comments, just leaving [this](https://pastebin.com/xeLsd9f0) here in case any one wants to check a better approach out.

Comment: @Jarvis Wasn't my downvote, but also I fail to see how my answer is any less efficient than yours. Sorting is not necessary in my answer if the input list is ordered (in the example given you could just reverse the list for an O(n) solution), but there's no guarantee that the general case is like this, in which case sorting should be done.

Comment: Hmm, I am assuming input can be anything, even the one where sorting takes worst-case time complexity. That aside, what do you think should be the answer for this sequence: `[13,12,10,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10]`? @Aplet123

Comment: @Jarvis It's unclear if order matters or if sequences can only be constrained to the order of the original list, but regardless, this just comes down the matter of commenting/uncommenting the list sorting line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a running sum, a running index, and iterate while it's still a sequence:

```py
mylist = [13,12,10,4,3,2]
mylist.sort() # this way sequences will be contiguous in the list

cur_index = 0
cur_sum = 0

while cur_index < len(mylist):
    # add the current element to the sum
    cur_sum += mylist[cur_index]
    # now iterate through while it's a contiguous sequence
    cur_index += 1
    while cur_index < len(mylist) and mylist[cur_index] == mylist[cur_index - 1] + 1:
        cur_index += 1

print(cur_sum)
```

Comment: I believe your code gives the answer for the sequence `[13,12,10,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10]` as 55, but if my understanding from the question is correct, it should be 40.

Comment: The answer seems to be off?  Please double check.

Answer (score 5):

@KennethRasch - earlier post would work. Alternatively, you can do this as well:

Try to find each possible subsequence's starting numbers as `starts` then just sum them to get answer.

```py
L = [13,12,10,4,3,2]
L.sort()

starts = [x for x in L if x-1 not in L]
print(starts)  

result = sum(starts)   
print(result)  # 24
```

Alternatively, you can put this into a function for future re-use it:

```py
def sum_lowests(L):
    '''L is a numbers sequence '''

    L.sort()
    starts = [x for x in L if x-1 not in L]
    #ans = sum(starts)       # can skip this step; just to make it clear

    return sum(starts)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    L = [13,12,10,4,3,2]
  
    A = [1, 2, 3, 5,6, 9,10,11, 16]

    print(sum_lowests(L))
    print(sum_lowests(A)) # 31
```

Comment: This gives me an error on: `result = sum(starts)`
>TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @KennethRasch - what's the error you got? I've re-run and it works just fine.

Comment: Interesting.  Do you change the input or modify anything? Or just cut-and-paste then run it with the `same  input`?  Try to see what's difference.

Comment: Were you not able to run the [code](https://pastebin.com/xeLsd9f0) I provided or having trouble to run/understand complex code? You should always consider about time complexity as an important priority. @KennethRasch

Comment: @Jarvis the code you provided was too overwhelming for me to fully comprehend, and for my small use case I found some of the other suggestions to fit better. But I appreciate you taking the time (and I wasn't the one down voting, if you are wondering)